# Prolog member not found

Tags: prolog, member

I have defined a code in PROLOG :

```
is_member(X, [X|_]).
is_member(X, [_|T]) :-
    is_member(X, T).
```

I am confused by these two outputs :

**out1:**

```
is_member('a', ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']).
>> True.
```

**out2:**

```
Chars = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'].
is_member('a', Chars).
>> Chars = [a|_2356]
```

Can someone help me out here? I though that output should be `True.`. I am trying to understand the logic here, but obviously I am lost.

Thank you for any help or advice in advance.

Comment: In Prolog, `Chars = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'].` is an expression that stands alone as its own logical statement since you ended with a period. Your `is_member('a', Chars).` has `Chars` as a new variable. Try a comma: `Chars = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a'], is_member('a', Chars).` The comma acts as a conjunction.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. It only prints Chars and its content but that's all.

Comment: That means it works. Whenever you get an answer with variable bindings, that means success. `'a'` is indeed a member of the list. Contrast the behavior with a similar query asking whether `x` is a member of the list.

Comment: It does almost the same, it just changes the number after `|`. So it prints `Chars = [x|_4338] ;`

Comment: When you ran Isabella's `x` case you reverted back to your incorrect way of doing it. If you used the method I showed, it would fail as expected. When you use `'a'`, the query succeeds and shows you the binding of the only variable you had, which was `Char`, as the solution. That's the way Prolog works. If it failed, it would have just said that and not shown you any variable results since it had failed. This is what you would see if you do Isabella's example correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how Prolog queries basically work.

First of all, a complete query ends with a *period* (`.`). When you execute:

```
Chars = [a, b, c, d].
```

This is a complete query since it ends in a period. When you execute a query, Prolog attempts to make it succeed via some binding of the given variables. If it is able to do so, it will simply display the variable bindings that result in success. In this particular case, the solution is trivial: `Chars` is bound to `[a, b, c, d]`.

Suppose you enter the above and then you follow this with:

```
is_member(a, Chars).
```

Since the previous query completed (it ended in a period), Prolog sees this `Chars` as a new variable. It is no longer bound to `[a, b, c, d]` because the previous query ended. Prolog looks at this query and determines what binding(s) for `Chars` will cause it to succeed. The result is:

```
Chars = [a|_2356]
```

Prolog is telling you that a valid solution is obtained by binding `Chars` to the list `[a|_2356]` which is any list that has `a` as its first element. What you didn't show is that Prolog prompts for additional solutions. If you press `;`, it shows you more solutions to the `is_member(a, Chars).` query:

```
3 ?- is_member(a, Chars).
Chars = [a|_5034] ;
Chars = [_5032, a|_5040] ;
Chars = [_5032, _5038, a|_5046] ;
...
```

In other words, `is_member(a, Chars)` has an infinite number of solutions. They are lists that have `a` as the first element, `a` as the second, etc.

In Prolog, if you want to establish a series of conditions that must all be true in sequence, you use a *comma*, not a *period*, to separate each condition, then end the whole thing in a period:

```
4 ?- Chars = [a,b,c,d], is_member(a, Chars).
Chars = [a, b, c, d] ;
false.
```

This query says you want to bind `Chars` to `[a, b, c, d]` *and* determine if `a` is a member of `Chars`. Prolog is then saying that it succeeded with one solution, `Chars = [a,b,c,d]`. Entering `;` seeks more solutions, which comes back *false* since there are no additional solutions.

Let's try Isabella's other example with `x`:

```
5 ?- Chars = [a,b,c,d], is_member(x, Chars).
false.
```

In this case, Prolog could not find a solution, so it simply fails (showing *false*).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You made it clear. And thank you for comprehensive answer!